# Are the language elements in Snow Crash supported by science?

Tags: science, snow-crash

After reading Snow Crash, I have to wonder if any of the premise or main/supporting plot points are backed by any science, or even plausible based on our current understanding.

For example:

> The whole idea of a metavirus, the metavirus coming from outside of earth, the nam-shub, being able to program humans with with a primitive base language, a biological virus being implemented as code, hackers being susceptible because of certain pathways...etc.

Little seems to actually be based on science, even at the time it was written. Was it just speculation to further the plot or is there something to it?

Comment: 'Is X science fiction' questions are off-topic, as per the FAQ. The problem is that it's too subjective (considered by who?) where the boundaries of genre lie. If you just want to know if there is any scientific basis in the story, then you could edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Questions about "Is X science fiction" are explicitly off-topic for this site. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: @Tony fixed the quetsion, although I don't think the definition of science fiction is too subjective. It has a pretty standard and well accepted definition. Are questions about "hard scifi" on topic, since that indisputably has a firm definition?

Comment: The edit looks good to me (I can't undo the close vote, but it will expire by itself, and I doubt there will be any further close-votes).

Comment: @JulieB There's no such thing as a "standard and well accepted definition" of science fiction, except maybe Damon Knight's "Science fiction is what I point to when I say 'science fiction'", which is indisputable but not very helpful, especially since Knight himself is no longer around to point to things for us.

Comment: @Mike maybe not a definition, but there is certainly a standard understanding of what constitutes scifi for the most part. It gets subjective to a point, but it should be clear for the most part when science fiction is distinct from science fantasy.

Comment: *A definition, offered by Rod Serling, is that "science fiction the improbable made possible; fantasy, the impossible made probable".[1] The meaning is that science fiction describes unlikely things that could possibly take place in the real world under certain conditions, while science fantasy gives a scientific veneer of realism to things that simply could not happen in the real world under any circumstances.* -- From wiki page on science fantasy. My point is that it should not be difficult to say if something is scifi or not based on our current understanding and plausibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not by any current science nor science at the time. Most of *Snow Crash* is made up of very interesting pseudo-science or promising (in 1992) [proto-science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protoscience).

As to the idea of a human "base language" - the search for a "universal language" has been a common theme of [myths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mythical_origins_of_language), [occult groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enochian), [pseudoscience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuro-linguistic_programming), and [pre-analytic philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Essay_towards_a_Real_Character_and_a_Philosophical_Language) since time immemorial. The reality is that [it is a completely open question in modern, fact-based linguistics as to whether there is even a single genesis of language in humans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Human_language). Let alone something as detailed and universally applicable as what's present in *Snow Crash*. Most modern linguists and psychologists also believe that language evolved continuously from non-language, i.e. there wasn't a primate who "could not" speak, and then her child who "could" - rather that communication grew gradually more complex over generations.

When *Snow Crash* was written, the field of [memetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memetics) was popular. Depending on who and when you ask, memetics is either an excellent explanation of cultural transfer,  a reasonable *model* of cultural transfer not tied strongly to reality, or a useless field that, at its best, provides a more complicated explanation for things we could already explain. "Memetics" survives today primarily as a way to alert someone they're going to be looking at cute cat pictures; one thing about a protoscience, is that very few [successfully play out into real sciences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme#Criticism_of_meme_theory).

The bare idea that language acts can influence people's views and actions is of course true, but by no measure can that statement, at that level, be called science.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on which elements you are referring to.

The idea of ideas behaving like genetic biological agents (aka [memes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme)) is definitely supported by science, as of 1976, way before "*Snow Crash*":

> The word meme is a shortening (modeled on gene) of mimeme (from Ancient Greek μίμημα Greek pronunciation: [míːmɛːma] mīmēma, "something imitated", from μιμεῖσθαι mimeisthai, "to imitate", from μῖμος mimos "mime") and it was coined by the British evolutionary biologist Richard Dawkins in *The Selfish Gene* (1976)

The idea that there may be a confluence between memetic information and genetic one is a fairly obvious one (for random example, think about genetic predisposition to obedience/rebellion).

The idea that "hackers being suspectible because of certain pathways" is somewhat plausible if ill defined. You can make a case that all good hackers have a form of Aspergers, and that has non-zero heritability and thus genetic influence.

Comment: I don't think a meme is what is talked about in Snow Crash. Memes can't directly program a person to do actions or cause overdose like symptoms.

Comment: @JulieB - um. "72 virgins".

Comment: -1 for "[memes are] definitely supported by science" and "all good hackers have a form of Aspergers", neither of which can be reasonably supported. _Memetics_ is a proto-science at best, and one that I get the impression is falling out of favor in the cogsci community for some years now - http://cfpm.org/jom-emit/2005/vol9/edmonds_b.html. The other statement is just bullshit.

Comment: The 72 virgins thing is indirect. Show me a meme that causes people to speak in tongues and you might have a point. Also, I have to agree that all good hackers may have a form of Asperger's is highly dubious.

Comment: @JulieB - do you understand what generally distinguishes a good hacker? Go and compare the checklist against a list of Aspergers' symptoms (I'm talking light fully functional Aspergers', not all the way on the Autism side of the spectrum).

Comment: Yes, I do understand. I also understand that many good hackers tend to be introverted and self-diagnose themselves with aspergers. I also know there are many good hackers who are not introverted or socially awkward and don't have Aspergers' like symptoms. Aspergers' at the moment seems to be like ADD was in the 90's.

Comment: @JulieB - do you realize that there are a lot of good hackers who ARE introverted and naturally socialy awkward but have a high enough IQ that they are ABLE to fake a convincing social interaction?

Comment: @DVK that sounds like speculation. Do you have any evidence for that, or is it just a personal theory/anecdotal observation?

Comment: @JulieB - anecdotal ovservation based on interacting with/knowing plenty of hackers. BTW, as a side note, food for thought: when you're dealing with someone with IQ over 130-140 who's expert at coding, any "proper cogsci" research is not gonna be reliable, since people like that are liable to be able to see through and reverse engineer all your tests and answer any which way they want.

Comment: "Programmers are magical creatures to whom psychology does not apply even though decades of research suggests it does!" Give me a break.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig - nobody was talking about generic programmers (1. programming merely gives you extra skills useful for the task, 2. we are talking people with 130-140+ IQ here, not "all" programmers). And yes, if someone is smart enough to know WHY a psychologist asks a specific question, they can give an answer tailored to convey any desired information. I know how social people behave an react. I can fake it VERY convincingly if required. Doesn't make me any less of a completely asocial animal. And i'm on a far left degree of IQ scale compared to the kinds of people we are talking about.

Comment: If this is you faking having a normal social reaction, you're doing a terrible job.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig - why would I fake a normal social reaction on a SFF Q/A site??? :)))

Comment: @DVK I know plenty of hackers as well. I have an IQ over 130 for all that is worth and make a pretty decent coder. I still think it's BS. It's become trendy to self-diagnose as an aspie if you're smarter than average and socially awkward. Doesn't make it so. I'm also skeptical of the claim that all decent hackers can fool trained psychologists. But we are way off topic now, so let us agree to disagree.